# Generating C# API client with NSwag.MSBuild

Tags: openapi, nswag

I have a .NET 6.0 API project. I am trying to generate a C# API client, so I added the NSwag.MSBuild nuget package and modified my API project file by adding the following:

```
  <Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" EnvironmentVariables="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" Command="$(NSwagExe_Net60) run nswag.json /variables:Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
  </Target>
```

I then created an nswag.json:

```
{
  "runtime": "Net60",
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToCSharpClient": {
      "clientBaseClass": null,
      "generateClientClasses": true,
      "generateClientInterfaces": true,
      "clientBaseInterface": null,
      "injectHttpClient": true,
      "disposeHttpClient": false,
      "output": "../Blah/Client.g.cs",
      "contractsOutputFilePath": "../Blah/Contracts.g.cs"
    }
  }
}
```

When the project builds it generates a client.g.cs in the Blah folder BUT the actual C# code it generates seems to be from some Pet API, for example here are a couple signatures in the IClient interface, I have no clue where this Pet API is coming from. Does anyone have any ideas:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Add a new pet to the store
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accept_Language">The language you prefer for messages. Supported values are en-AU, en-CA, en-GB, en-US</param>
        /// <param name="cookieParam">Some cookie</param>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task AddPetAsync(object body, string accept_Language, long cookieParam);

        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
        /// <summary>
        /// Add a new pet to the store
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accept_Language">The language you prefer for messages. Supported values are en-AU, en-CA, en-GB, en-US</param>
        /// <param name="cookieParam">Some cookie</param>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task AddPetAsync(object body, string accept_Language, long cookieParam, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken);

        /// <summary>
        /// Update an existing pet
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accept_Language">The language you prefer for messages. Supported values are en-AU, en-CA, en-GB, en-US</param>
        /// <param name="cookieParam">Some cookie</param>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task UpdatePetAsync(object body, string accept_Language, long cookieParam);

        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
        /// <summary>
        /// Update an existing pet
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accept_Language">The language you prefer for messages. Supported values are en-AU, en-CA, en-GB, en-US</param>
        /// <param name="cookieParam">Some cookie</param>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task UpdatePetAsync(object body, string accept_Language, long cookieParam, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken);

        /// <summary>
        /// Find pet by ID
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="petId">ID of pet to return</param>
        /// <returns>successful operation</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Pet> GetPetByIdAsync(long petId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the default behavior of the NSwag generator. You have to specify  input for reading your specification.

In my case i have create a yaml file for api specification.

nswag.json file looks like following.

```
{
  "runtime": "Net60",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
  "fromDocument": {
    "json": "",
    "url": "openapi.yaml",
    "output": null
  }
},
"codeGenerators": {
"openApiToCSharpClient": {
  "clientBaseClass": null,
  "generateClientClasses": true,
  "generateClientInterfaces": true,
  "clientBaseInterface": null,
  "injectHttpClient": true,
  "disposeHttpClient": false,
  "output": "../Blah/Client.g.cs",
  "contractsOutputFilePath": "../Blah/Contracts.g.cs"
  }
 }
}
```

For futher details you can read [here](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1685).

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have `ASP.NET Core API` project `MyApi.csproj` you want to autogenerate API clients for to a separate project `MyApiClients.csproj` under folder `Generated` to `Clients.g.cs`. The projects folders structure:

- MyApi

  - Controllers
  - .temp (folder generate Clients.g.cs to from controllers definition on after build)
- MyApiClients

  - Generated (target folder to copy Clients.g.cs from MyApi/.temp once generated)

**To make your API project autogenerating on build (in the example below on `AfterBuild`) you need to:**

1. Make sure you have `NSwag.MSBuild` `NuGet` package added to `MyApi.csproj`
2. Add `MyApi/nswag.json` config file for `NSwag` (you can use [NSwagStudio](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/NSwagStudio) UI to configure settings or just manually edit `JSON` if you are familiar with the settings)
3. Then add `MSBuild` target to generate and copy API clients to target location:

[image]

This is trimmed `nswag.json` file with most of mmitted default settings:

[image]